# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity. - Invalid cookie name ["session_id - Rails 7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I upgraded from Rails 7.0.8 to 7.1.0 and got this error.

The only unexpected thing I found is that the cookie name is **["session_id** instead of just **session_id**. So maybe somewhere it adds [". But I don't know where to look at.

It works on development/staging/production when running on my local machine. The issue is only after deployed to a remote server.

**FORM (SIGN UP**)
**Head**

**Form**
`<form data-turbo="false" class="space-y-4" id="new_user" action="/en/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">`

**Registration controller**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

def configure_sign_up_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up,
       keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :terms_of_service, :coupon_code, :currency_code, :referral, :locale, :referrer, :via, utm: [:source, :campaign, :medium, :content, :term] ])
   end
```

**config/enviroment/staging.rb**

```
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" }}
  config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_session", expire_after: 1.year
```

**Gemfile.lock**
devise (4.9.3)
rails (7.1.2)

[image]